# Matching words in a list against a stringarray in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, replace

I need to find and replace a list of words given by the user.
My application reads line by line in an HTML file and I want to verify if there is a word from the list and replace it with a blank space.
This is what I have until now but I think I will have to modify my hole code in order to get what I want.

```
    private static void PrintFile(File source) throws IOException {
    String s;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(source);
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("Results.txt");
    while ((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
        pw.println(s.replaceAll("&#160;", "") //Words to be replaced.
                .replaceAll("<br>", "")
                .replaceAll("&amp;", "")
                .replaceAll("</p>", "")
                .replaceAll("</body>","")
                .replaceAll("</html>", "")
                .replaceAll("<remote object=\"#DEFAULT\">&gt;", ""));
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

I accept any suggestions, the list idea may not be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove HTML markup as simple as this with [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org):

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
  return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Also have a look at [`Cleaner` and `Whitelist`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) to sanatize documents individually.

Comment: Thanks, Jsoup helped a lot, in fact I improved mi solution by filtering words I needed once my html file was parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Because `String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` takes a regexp as its first parameter I would suggest to use `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence replacement)` instead to avoid undesired behavior.

Other than that I can't see a big problem in your code.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind including [apache commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) into your project, you can use `StringUtils.replaceEach` and be done with it.